# Kubernetes: Failure to connect to a pod IP

Tags: kubernetes, minikube

I followed this tutorial: https://dev.to/narasimha1997/communication-between-microservices-in-a-kubernetes-cluster-1n41.

I made the following steps:

1. Created the file web-server.yaml with the content:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: webapp1
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: webapp1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: webapp1
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: webapp1
        image: katacoda/docker-http-server:latest
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
```

2. ran `kubectl create -f web-server.yaml`
3. ran `kubectl get pods -o wide` and received:

```
NAME                       READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE   IP           NODE               NOMINATED NODE   READINESS GATES
webapp1-6b54fb89d9-ct7fk   1/1     Running   0          17m   10.46.0.30   ip-172-31-56-227   <none>           <none>
```

4. However, when I run `curl http://10.46.0.30` after a few seconds I get the error message:

> curl: (28) Failed to connect to 10.46.0.30 port 80 after 21551 ms:
> Couldn't connect to server

Does someone know why?

Comment: You don't seem to have created a Service matching your Deployment, but this is usually required.  The cluster-internal IP addresses aren't usually reachable from outside the cluster.

Comment: @DavidMaze I tried to add a service and I don't see a change in behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Since minikube is a Virtual machine, I need to SSH to this VM. I do it with the command:
`minikube ssh`
and then running:
`curl http://10.244.0.31` gives:

`<h1>This request was processed by host: webapp1-b8b46687f-xxc2s</h1>`

Answer (score 0):

Based on the [tutorial](https://dev.to/narasimha1997/communication-between-microservices-in-a-kubernetes-cluster-1n41), you should [connect via ssh](https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/commands/ssh/) on one of the nodes to do the curl.

`minikube kubectl -- get pods -o wide` command should show the pods IP

`minikube kubectl -- get nodes` command should show the cluster nodes so that you can connect to it

minikube ssh -n <node-name> command will connect you to the node.

```
uservm@instance-1:~$ minikube ssh -n minikube
```

Once connected to the node, you can do the curl and get the expected out.

```
docker@minikube:~$ curl http://10.244.0.3

This request was processed by host: webapp1-b8b46687f-rbjgl
```

Note that this instructions are also indicated in the tutorial.